# Start and close element on condition in AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've a HTML structure which looks like this :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="md-4">1</div>
<div class="md-4">2</div>
<div class="md-4">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="md-4">4</div>
<div class="md-4">5</div>
<div class="md-4">6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="md-4">7</div>
<div class="md-4">8</div>
<div class="md-4">9</div>
</div>
```

and I've JS :

```
var abc = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

currently as per my structure I can't directly run ng-repeat as after every 3 records I want  starts and ends

I want something similar like

```
<div ng-repeat="val in abc" class="row" ng-if="$index%3==0">
<div>{{val}}</div>
</div>
```

but above codes don't work and I know its incorrect way but I want something similar to that

Answer (score 0):

please try with this code:

```
<div ng-repeat="val in abc track by $index" class="row" ng-if="$index%3==0">
<div>{{val}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've used lodash before

```
var arr = _.chunk(abc,3);
//makes your array like [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

<div ng-repeat = "a in arr" class = "row">
  <div ng-repeat="b in a" class="md-4">{{b}}</div>
</div>
```

you can lookup lodash [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk)